# Optimizing slow SELECT query (postgresql 9.6.5)

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

In an app called `Links`, users post interesting content in a forum like interface, and others post replies or comments under this publicly posted content.

These posted replies are saved in a postgresql table named `links_publicreply` (postgresql 9.6.5 DB).

One query run on the table keep on cropping up in the `slow_log` (greater than `500ms`). This relates to showing the most-recent 25 public replies accumulated under a given piece of shared content.

Here's a sample from the slow log:

**LOG:  duration: 1614.030 ms  statement:**

```
 SELECT "links_publicreply"."id",
       "links_publicreply"."submitted_by_id",
       "links_publicreply"."answer_to_id",
       "links_publicreply"."submitted_on",
       "links_publicreply"."description",
       "links_publicreply"."abuse",
       "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."username",
       "links_userprofile"."id",
       "links_userprofile"."user_id",
       "links_userprofile"."score",
       "links_userprofile"."avatar",
       "links_link"."id",
       "links_link"."description",
       "links_link"."submitter_id",
       "links_link"."submitted_on",
       "links_link"."reply_count",
       "links_link"."latest_reply_id"
FROM   "links_publicreply"
       INNER JOIN "links_link"
               ON ( "links_publicreply"."answer_to_id" = "links_link"."id" )
       INNER JOIN "auth_user"
               ON ( "links_publicreply"."submitted_by_id" = "auth_user"."id" )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "links_userprofile"
                    ON ( "auth_user"."id" = "links_userprofile"."user_id" )
WHERE  "links_publicreply"."answer_to_id" = 8936203
ORDER  BY "links_publicreply"."id" DESC
LIMIT  25
```

Here are the `explain analyze` results of the said query: **https://explain.depesz.com/s/pVZ5**

According to that, ~70% of the query time seems to be taken up by index scan. But to an accidental DBA like myself, it isn't immediately obvious what optimization I can do to make this more performant. Perhaps a composite index on `links_publicreply.answer_to_id, links_publicreply.id`?

It would greatly help me learn if a domain expert can furnish guidance + intuition on solving this class of problem.

---

P.s. `\d links_publicreply` is:

```
                                      Table "public.links_publicreply"
     Column      |           Type           |                           Modifiers                            
-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_publicreply_id_seq'::regclass)
 submitted_by_id | integer                  | not null
 answer_to_id    | integer                  | not null
 submitted_on    | timestamp with time zone | not null
 description     | text                     | not null
 category        | character varying(20)    | not null
 seen            | boolean                  | not null
 abuse           | boolean                  | not null
 device          | character varying(10)    | default '1'::character varying
Indexes:
    "links_publicreply_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_publicreply_answer_to_id" btree (answer_to_id)
    "links_publicreply_submitted_by_id" btree (submitted_by_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_publicreply_answer_to_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (answer_to_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_publicreply_submitted_by_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (submitted_by_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "links_report" CONSTRAINT "links_report_which_publicreply_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_publicreply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_seen" CONSTRAINT "links_seen_which_reply_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_reply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_link" CONSTRAINT "publicreplyposter_link_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (latest_reply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, trying to reduce the number of calling the index. This filter `answer_to_id = 8936203` returns `14740` rows which used to check on the other tables. However you need only top `25` of `id`.
What if you `LIMIT 25` then `JOIN` the other tables.

```
WITH tmp_links_publicreply AS (
   SELECT ...
   FROM links_publicreply
   WHERE  "links_publicreply"."answer_to_id" = 8936203
   ORDER  BY "links_publicreply"."id" DESC
   LIMIT  25  
)
SELECT 
FROM tmp_links_publicreply t 
JOIN ... 
JOIN ...
```

The query above would work correctly if you have the constraint between `links_publicreply` and 2 tables `links_link` and `auth_user`. Why? Supposed that, you `LIMIT 25`, then found nothing when `JOIN` because there is no rows in `links_link` related to `answer_to_id = 8936203`.

Then, creating the new index on `answer_to_id, id DESC`.

*Note*: `WITH` (*query above*) called [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/queries-with.html)